Command line to for opening FF without address bar, menu bar, etc. but not Kiosk mode
I do not want Kiosk mode, but do need ability to open it via command line so that only the title bar (and borders around the app.
The most current available entry on the matter in the Mozilla site no longer works (at least for me on latest release as of posting date ) --
firefox.exe -ssb urlhere
Chromium browsers just work by passing their command per avialable documentation from Google.
This is for use to launch a local help/users guide from a Windows application. Can do so on Chrome/Edge, but leaving out FF is less than ideal.

This question is similar to: How can I launch FireFox with no window frame or tabs / address bar?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, sorry. The option from your recommended link does not have the title bar or frame so user can't close it except via Task Manger, nor move or resize.

The answers posted there do appear to give the current correct info, though. The info there and the links to specific Mozilla docs suggest that SSB is not currently supported in FF.

Every combination of commands directly from Mozilla and numerous posts on other websites (-SSB, etc.) fail.  Won't do it.  Every browser based on Chromium (which is all other browsers that aren't Safari or on a Mac) - works.  Sigh.  And Mozilla wonders why they can't crack double-digit use.  What a shame.
If anyone somehow makes it happen, post away.

Not to put too fine a point on it, but us nerds with our niche needs don't crack double digits. Firefox main "just be a good browser" function is very good and would meet the needs of the vast majority of general users. Especially considering the most common browsers ignore technical users like you and I and remove functions we want without notice all the time.

Corporate users that choose FF for privacy are not a nerd niche.
